# Is it possible that cy.get() prevents iframe loading?

Tags: javascript, iframe, cypress

I have iframe element on the page I am working with in Cypress. I use a function for inputting the text into the iframe:

```js
function inputTextToIframe(text) {
  cy.get('iframe').then(($iframe) => {
    const $body = $iframe.contents().find('body');
    cy.wrap($body).type(text);
  });
}
```

The function works fine. But there is one problem regarding the element visibility: it must be visible before the function starts working. So I have to force `cy.wait()` with the time interval which is enough for the element to be completely loaded (about 10 seconds). And only then I can apply the function. If I call the function without `cy.wait()` the iframe never comes out on the page whatever `defaultCommandTimeout` I use in my cypress.json. E.g. I use `cy.wait(10000)` and the code works after iframe is loaded, but it does not work if I configure cypress.json to `"defaultCommandTimeout": 30000` instead of using `cy.wait()` because the iframe never appears on the page and Cypress says it does not exist. It looks like `cy.get()` instruction prevents the element loading. Is it possible?

Comment: Can you mention in the code where are you using `cy.wait()`

Comment: it('Test', () => {

    approvalPageObj.firstViewBtnClick();

    cy.wait(10000);

    inputTextToIframe(approval_rejectionMsg);

  });

});

Comment: Looks very strange. Right now tried to run the code on my home machine which is 4 times weaker than those used on my workplace and the code works. It runs extreemly slowly taking much more time but it works...

Answer (score 1):

The Cypress setting `defaultCommandTimeout` will only work when your callback is invoked with `.should()`, but not when it uses `.then()`.

Try it this way, also including an `expect()` to trigger a retry...

```js
function inputTextToIframe(text) {
  cy.get('iframe')
    .should(($iframe) => {
      const $body = $iframe.contents().find('body')
      expect($body.length).to.be.gt(0)                // invoke retry
      cy.wrap($body).type(text);
    });
}
```

That specific test may not be enough, the body may exist but not have it's content loaded.

I recommend using a package like [cypress-iframe](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cypress-iframe) which throws a lot of different checks into the test.